# What does the statement "dht22_dat[j/8] <<= 1;" mean and how does it work?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

What is the meaning of the statement:

```
dht22_dat[j/8] <<= 1;
if (counter > 16)
dht22_dat[j/8] |= 1;
j++;
```

it is a part of c-code to read sensor dht22 (temperature & humidity) with raspberry pi4. here is the complete code:

https://github.com/Seeed-Studio/Grove-RaspberryPi/blob/master/Grove%20-%20Temperature%20and%20Humidity%20Sensor%20Pro/dht22.c

Comment: It shifts `dht22_dat[j/8]` left one bit, leaving bit 0 clear.  https://www.w3schools.com/c/c_operators.php

Answer (score 1):

```
dht22_dat[j/8] <<= 1;
```

From the array `dht22_dat`, take the element with the index `j / 8`, shift its bits one to the left, and assign the result back to that same element.

`<<=`, in this regard, is similar to e.g. `+=` or `-=`, just for the shift-left operation `<<`.

The next line:

```
dht22_dat[j/8] |= 1;
```

This takes the same element, and applies a bitwise and (`| 1`) to it.

Ref. [Assignment Operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment).